# AWS snapshots created without policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, backup, snapshot

in my AWS snapshots, I see, that there are snapshots created without policy, and I don't know, hot to disable them.

In my "*Lifecycle Manager*" I see only one policy, and it creates snapshot every day, and keep them for 2 weeks.
Those snapshots have description added "*Created for policy: policy-0fd537dfc2b885c39 schedule: Daily*".
And kept only for 2 weeks, then deleted automatically.

But there are also some snapshots without description, which aren't deleted and kept forever. Their creation date is about 11:45PM (East Europe time).

Snapshot list, with unknown snapshots in red border.
[image: created snapshots]

The only policy defined:
[image: the only snapshot policy]

Are they created by some automatic volume backup, or how?
I didn't have any cron jobs on the server.

What can I do to disable them? Where to find their configuration?

I appreciate any help :)
Kind regards,
Wojtek

Comment: Do you create any AMIs? They also generate Snapshots. You definitely have _something_ running at 12:45.

Comment: Yes, I have 3 AMIs, but I don't see any settings for backup there. What is more, all of them have 30 GB in size, so there are not the ones I mentioned in my post :(

Comment: You can use AWS CloudTrail to look for the APi events that created the Snapshots. A user identity (eg IAM Role or IAM User) will be associated with those events. That should help you figure out how/what is creating those snapshots each night at 12:45am.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein this AWS CloudTrail guides me to solution :)
I found some Rules in Amazon EventBridge, which creates Auto-Snapshots of my volumes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS CloudTrail to look for the API events that created the Snapshots. A user identity (eg IAM Role or IAM User) will be associated with those events.

That should help you figure out how/what is creating those snapshots each night at 12:45am.